shorted component on laptop motherboard
Some youtube videos on motherboard faulfinding show using a thermal camera to find a shorted component.The component shows up getting very hot. So if it is shorted will the resistance not be similar to the traces i.e much smaller than the other components around it that don't appear to get hot.

your thinking is correct ... but, it depends on the size of the component leads

You don't ask an answerable question. Please add one so it can be answered. Also the logic is wrong. Some component such as a regulator may heat up because something has shorted after it and the shorted component may stay cool because a short will not dissipate any power and will not heat up.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's figurative speech. Shorted is used in that case as a synonym for "dead component, gets hot" under power. It does not literally mean "acts like a piece of copper".
And you're totally correct that a component that fails with resistance close to that of copper, will not really get very got, as most of the heat will be dissipated by the PCB copper instead, as there's way more of the latter.
Thankfully, most "shorted" components aren't really shorted - they just have a resistance much lower than normal, but far from a dead short.
